# Добавление значений в ArrayList

Tags: java, android

Получаю json с сервера, чтобы в дальнейшем передать в кастомный адаптер. При запуске приложение вылетает ошибка

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method
>   'boolean java.util.ArrayList.add(java.lang.Object)' on a null object
>   reference

Как исправить?

```
    public class JSONTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

        HttpURLConnection connection = null;
        BufferedReader reader = null;
        while (true) {

            try {
                URL url = new URL(params[0]);
                connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                connection.connect();

                InputStream stream = connection.getInputStream();

                reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(stream));

                StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();

                String line = "";
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    buffer.append(line);
                }
                return buffer.toString();

            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                if (connection != null) {
                    connection.disconnect();
                }
                try {
                    if (reader != null) {
                        reader.close();
                    }
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            return null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);

        if (result != null) {


            JSONObject jsonObject = null;

            try {
                jsonObject = new JSONObject(result);

                JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("wall");

                for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject productObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

                    UList.add(new CSD(
                            productObject.getString("name"),
                            productObject.getString("text")
                    ));
                }

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }



        } else {

        }


    }


}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

у вас нет инициализации масива.
сделайте ее при обявлении масива, примерно так

```
List<CSD> UList = new ArrayList<>();
```

если не поможет, то укажите в какой строке ошибка